# Archive with Xcode gives AdBanner errors

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, release, launch

I've built and released a product for google play, I'm trying to release it to apple now. I've been following several guides through the long process but when I go to archive my product I get a lot of errors referring to Adbanners.

The most common one errors are Apple Mach-O Linker Error. I've been making apps for a year or so but this is my first attempt with Xcode so I'm probably overlooking something in the build settings or something but I've watched tutorials and searched the forums and I'm still stuck.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. When I went to validate my project settings Xcode automatically selected the architecture for me which caused all the errors.

This link here helped me figure it out.

http://www.mobinett.com/2013/09/20/ios-7-xcode-5-project-build-settings-for-architectures-and-arm64-support/